# Rails 4: Modeling & Designing a Test Bank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

So I am in the process of modeling/designing an academic test bank for users on my app, and I was wondering if there's some default Rails way to do something like this:

Essentially, the test bank will have subject categories (such as `Math`, `History`, `English`), and within each subject category, there will be folders for classes that correspond to the subject. (for instance, in the `Math` category, we would have subcategories `Math 101`, `Math 128`,`Math 185`, and so on. Finally, within the class categories, we would have the actual tests themselves (as PDFs).

I know the best thing to do is to have a `TestFile` model, declare that it `has_attached_file` (with Paperclip), and declare that `ClassCategory` `has_many` `Tests`. But I'm a bit confused on what associations to use everything else.

**My guess:**

TestBank.rb:

```
has_many SubjectCategory
```

SubjectCategory.rb

```
belongs_to TestBank
has_many ClassCategory
```

ClassCategory.rb

```
belongs_to SubjectCategory
has_many TestFile
```

TestFile.rb:

```
has_attached_file :pdf
belongs_to ClassCategory
```

Is this correct?

Furthermore, how do I work out all of the routing? If I recall, nesting resources more than 1 level deep is not ideal, so how would I work this out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That seems reasonable. As for the routing, what you are describing here are model assocations. Each of the models should have its own controller that you don't need to nest unless you want to. `resources :controller_name` in `routes.rb` will set up each controller without namespacing. Personally, I'd namespace like this:

```
/:subject_category/:class_category
```

From what I can tell you don't have a lot of information needed for the `TestFile` so I'd consider calling them via the association - i.e., Math 101 (a :class_category) has all the resources for Math 101 on its page, or loads them in via JS partials, perhaps. That's personal taste though. At work we've got a route nested 4 deep because it's most appropriate to generate a URL that looks correct given your location in the app. Not ideal, but it doesn't cause problems either.

Comment: why would one create a nested relationship between models yet not implement the routes as such. If im adding Category I want it to belong_to a Subject so nesting this CRUD would be logical

Comment: I recently did an app that (let's say) had Users and Posts; in terms of navigation, both were of equal importance in the hierarchy, so although a Post belonged to a User I decided not to nest it. It's based on the likelihood of an end user wanting to parse the url bar, posts/123 is easier. As I say, at work we deeply nest instead. I'm not dogmatic about either but the OP said they wanted to keep it to two levels, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this up by using Ruby on rails' sweet association system, I've read your idea and decided to alter some classnames

resources:

- Subject (Math, English etc.)
- Category(M101, M128 etc.)
- SubjectCategory(combines subject and category so category isn't restricted to 1 subject.)
- Test

Association logic:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subject_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :subject_categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subject_categories
  has_many :subjects, through: :subject_categories
end

class SubjectCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject
  belongs_to :category

  has_many :tests
end
```

and as the combination of the 2 decides which tests are related:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject_category

  mount_uploader :source, TestUploader // this is carrierwave related do your own thing here.
end
```

EDIT:

Also the routes:

```
resources :subjects do
  resources :categories
  resources :subject_categories, only: :create
end
```

for more info please refer to the rails guide:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks. Another question: (for sake of simplicity let's say that the nested resources are only 1 level deep: tests are nested inside of categories). I have a user to be able to click a button bringing them to a form to create a new test entry, and I want the form to let the user choose what category the test will be placed under. However, the route that corresponds to a new testfile is `new_recruiting_category_prep_file_path`, which requires a recruiting_category_id... how do I get past this?

Comment: new_recruiting_category_prep_file_path(recruiting_category_id), also if the above answer helped think about marking it as the right answer.